# Do limits on political activity of 501(c)(3) organizations apply to their activities outside the US?

Tags: non-profit

501(c)(3) orgs have limits on their political activity - for example, they can't support political campaigns and intervene in elections of public officials.

Do these limits apply to political activities outside the US? Can, for example, a 501(c)(3) direct funds to a foreign presidential campaign? If not, what about other types of US non-profits?

Disregard that there might be local regulations that prohibit foreign funding of political campaigns - for the purposes of this question I'm only interested in this situation from the standpoint of US law.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer**

> Do limits on political activity of 501(c)(3) organizations apply to
> their activities outside the US?

Yes. There is no exception for foreign activity.

A 501(c)(3) organization does have to be U.S. based to qualify for the charitable deduction from federal income taxes (26 U.S.C. § 170), however, while the charitable deduction from gift and estate taxes also includes foreign charities.

**Analysis**

The prohibition on non-profits engaging in politics in the United States is found at 26 U.S.C. § [501(c)(3)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/501) which states:

> (c)(3)Corporations, and any community chest, fund, or foundation,
> organized and operated exclusively for religious, charitable,
> scientific, testing for public safety, literary, or educational
> purposes, or to foster national or international amateur sports
> competition (but only if no part of its activities involve the
> provision of athletic facilities or equipment), or for the prevention
> of cruelty to children or animals, no part of the net earnings of
> which inures to the benefit of any private shareholder or individual,
> **no substantial part of the activities of which is carrying on propaganda, or otherwise attempting, to influence legislation (except
> as otherwise provided in subsection (h)), and which does not
> participate in, or intervene in (including the publishing or
> distributing of statements), any political campaign on behalf of (or
> in opposition to) any candidate for public office.**

and 26 U.S.C. § 501(h) which states:

> (h)*Expenditures by public charities to influence legislation*
>
> (1)*General rule*
>
> In the case of an organization to which this subsection applies,
> exemption from taxation under subsection (a) shall be denied because a
> substantial part of the activities of such organization consists of
> carrying on propaganda, or otherwise attempting, to influence
> legislation, but only if such organization normally—
>
> (A)makes lobbying expenditures in excess of the lobbying ceiling
> amount for such organization for each taxable year, or
>
> (B)makes grass roots expenditures in excess of the grass roots ceiling
> amount for such organization for each taxable year.
>
> (2)*Definitions*
>
> For purposes of this subsection—
>
> (A)Lobbying expenditures
>
> The term “lobbying expenditures” means expenditures for the purpose of
> influencing legislation (as defined in section 4911(d)).
>
> (B)Lobbying ceiling amount
>
> The lobbying ceiling amount for any organization for any taxable year
> is 150 percent of the lobbying nontaxable amount for such organization
> for such taxable year, determined under section 4911.
>
> (C)Grass roots expenditures
>
> The term “grass roots expenditures” means expenditures for the purpose
> of influencing legislation (as defined in section 4911(d) without
> regard to paragraph (1)(B) thereof).
>
> (D)Grass roots ceiling amount
>
> The grass roots ceiling amount for any organization for any taxable
> year is 150 percent of the grass roots nontaxable amount for such
> organization for such taxable year, determined under section 4911.
>
> (3)*Organizations to which this subsection applies*
>
> This subsection shall apply to any organization which has elected (in
> such manner and at such time as the Secretary may prescribe) to have
> the provisions of this subsection apply to such organization and
> which, for the taxable year which includes the date the election is
> made, is described in subsection (c)(3) and—
>
> (A)is described in paragraph (4), and
>
> (B)is not a disqualified organization under paragraph (5).
>
> (4)*Organizations permitted to elect to have this subsection apply*
>
> An organization is described in this paragraph if it is described in—
>
> (A)section 170(b)(1)(A)(ii) (relating to educational institutions),
>
> (B)section 170(b)(1)(A)(iii) (relating to hospitals and medical
> research organizations),
>
> (C)section 170(b)(1)(A)(iv) (relating to organizations supporting
> government schools),
>
> (D)section 170(b)(1)(A)(vi) (relating to organizations publicly
> supported by charitable contributions),
>
> (E)section 170(b)(1)(A)(ix) (relating to agricultural research
> organizations),
>
> (F)section 509(a)(2) (relating to organizations publicly supported by
> admissions, sales, etc.), or
>
> (G)section 509(a)(3) (relating to organizations supporting certain
> types of public charities) except that for purposes of this
> subparagraph, section 509(a)(3) shall be applied without regard to the
> last sentence of section 509(a).
>
> (5)*Disqualified organizations*
>
> For purposes of paragraph (3) an organization is a disqualified
> organization if it is—
>
> (A)described in section 170(b)(1)(A)(i) (relating to churches),
>
> (B)an integrated auxiliary of a church or of a convention or
> association of churches, or
>
> (C)a member of an affiliated group of organizations (within the
> meaning of section 4911(f)(2)) if one or more members of such group is
> described in subparagraph (A) or (B).
>
> (6)*Years for which election is effective*
>
> An election by an organization under this subsection shall be
> effective for all taxable years of such organization which—
>
> (A)end after the date the election is made, and
>
> (B)begin before the date the election is revoked by such organization
> (under regulations prescribed by the Secretary).
>
> (7)*No effect on certain organizations*
>
> With respect to any organization for a taxable year for which—
>
> (A)such organization is a disqualified organization (within the
> meaning of paragraph (5)), or
>
> (B)an election under this subsection is not in effect for such
> organization, nothing in this subsection or in section 4911 shall be
> construed to affect the interpretation of the phrase, “no substantial
> part of the activities of which is carrying on propaganda, or
> otherwise attempting, to influence legislation,” under subsection
> (c)(3).
>
> (8)*Affiliated organizations*
>
> For rules regarding affiliated organizations, see section 4911(f).

and [26 U.S.C. § 4911](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/4911) which states in the definitional subsection:

> (d)*Influencing legislation*
>
> (1)*General rule*
>
> Except as otherwise provided in paragraph (2), for purposes of this
> section, the term “influencing legislation” means—
>
> (A)any attempt to influence any legislation through an attempt to
> affect the opinions of the general public or any segment thereof, and
>
> (B)any attempt to influence any legislation through communication with
> any member or employee of a legislative body, or with any government
> official or employee who may participate in the formulation of the
> legislation.
>
> (2)*Exceptions*
>
> For purposes of this section, the term “influencing legislation”, with
> respect to an organization, does not include—
>
> (A)making available the results of nonpartisan analysis, study, or
> research;
>
> (B)providing of technical advice or assistance (where such advice
> would otherwise constitute the influencing of legislation) to a
> governmental body or to a committee or other subdivision thereof in
> response to a written request by such body or subdivision, as the case
> may be;
>
> (C)appearances before, or communications to, any legislative body with
> respect to a possible decision of such body which might affect the
> existence of the organization, its powers and duties, tax-exempt
> status, or the deduction of contributions to the organization;
>
> (D)communications between the organization and its bona fide members
> with respect to legislation or proposed legislation of direct interest
> to the organization and such members, other than communications
> described in paragraph (3); and
>
> (E)any communication with a governmental official or employee, other
> than—
>
> (i)a communication with a member or employee of a legislative body
> (where such communication would otherwise constitute the influencing
> of legislation), or
>
> (ii)a communication the principal purpose of which is to influence
> legislation.
>
> (3)*Communications with members*
>
> (A)A communication between an organization and any bona fide member of
> such organization to directly encourage such member to communicate as
> provided in paragraph (1)(B) shall be treated as a communication
> described in paragraph (1)(B).
>
> (B)A communication between an organization and any bona fide member of
> such organization to directly encourage such member to urge persons
> other than members to communicate as provided in either subparagraph
> (A) or subparagraph (B) of paragraph (1) shall be treated as a
> communication described in paragraph (1)(A).